# "roslaunch explore_stage explore.launch" problem

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, explore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

plz heeelllpp! :(
i used explore_stage before, but after upgrade my ubuntu, it gave me this error!

> 

```
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ roslaunch explore_stage explore.launch
... logging to /home/mohsen/.ros/log/e3e2f4c6-bca0-11e2-b4c1-001c259b7f6b/roslaunch-mohsen-ThinkPad-R500-5445.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

WARNING: ignoring defunct <master /> tag
started roslaunch server http://mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:43843/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /explore/close_loops
 * /explore/explore_costmap/base_scan/clearing
 * /explore/explore_costmap/base_scan/data_type
 * /explore/explore_costmap/base_scan/expected_update_rate
 * /explore/explore_costmap/base_scan/marking
 * /explore/explore_costmap/base_scan/observation_persistance
 * /explore/explore_costmap/base_scan/sensor_frame
 * /explore/explore_costmap/circumscribed_radius
 * /explore/explore_costmap/cost_scaling_factor
 * /explore/explore_costmap/global_frame
 * /explore/explore_costmap/height
 * /explore/explore_costmap/inflation_radius
 * /explore/explore_costmap/inscribed_radius
 * /explore/explore_costmap/lethal_cost_threshold
 * /explore/explore_costmap/map_type
 * /explore/explore_costmap/max_obstacle_height
 * /explore/explore_costmap/observation_sources
 * /explore/explore_costmap/obstacle_range
 * /explore/explore_costmap/origin_x
 * /explore/explore_costmap/origin_y
 * /explore/explore_costmap/publish_frequency
 * /explore/explore_costmap/raytrace_range
 * /explore/explore_costmap/resolution
 * /explore/explore_costmap/robot_base_frame
 * /explore/explore_costmap/rolling_window
 * /explore/explore_costmap/static_map
 * /explore/explore_costmap/track_unknown_space
 * /explore/explore_costmap/transform_tolerance
 * /explore/explore_costmap/update_frequency
 * /explore/explore_costmap/width
 * /explore/gain_scale
 * /explore/orientation_scale
 * /explore/potential_scale
 * /move_base/NavfnROS/transform_tolerance
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_th
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_y
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/dwa
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/escape_reset_dist
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/escape_reset_theta
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/goal_distance_bias
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_lookahead
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_scoring
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_scoring_timestep
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/holonomic_robot
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_th
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_in_place_vel_th
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_th
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/occdist_scale
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/oscillation_reset_dist
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/path_distance_bias
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_granularity
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_time
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/simple_attractor
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/transform_tolerance
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vtheta_samples
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vx_samples
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/world_model
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance
 * /move_base/footprint
 * /move_base/global_costmap/base_scan/clearing
 * /move_base/global_costmap/base_scan/data_type
 * /move_base/global_costmap/base_scan/expected_update_rate
 * /move_base/global_costmap/base_scan/marking
 * /move_base/global_costmap/base_scan/observation_persistance
 * /move_base/global_costmap/base_scan/sensor_frame
 * /move_base/global_costmap/circumscribed_radius
 * /move_base/global_costmap/cost_scaling_factor
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame
 * /move_base/global_costmap/height
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_radius
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inscribed_radius
 * /move_base/global_costmap/lethal_cost_threshold
 * /move_base/global_costmap/map_type
 * /move_base/global_costmap/max_obstacle_height
 * /move_base/global_costmap/observation_sources
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range
 * /move_base/global_costmap/origin_x
 * /move_base/global_costmap/origin_y
 * /move_base/global_costmap/publish_frequency
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range
 * /move_base/global_costmap/resolution
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame
 * /move_base/global_costmap/rolling_window
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/transform_tolerance
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency
 * /move_base/global_costmap/width
 * /move_base/local_costmap/base_scan/clearing
 * /move_base/local_costmap/base_scan/data_type
 * /move_base/local_costmap/base_scan/expected_update_rate
 * /move_base/local_costmap/base_scan/marking
 * /move_base/local_costmap/base_scan/observation_persistance
 * /move_base/local_costmap/base_scan/sensor_frame
 * /move_base/local_costmap/circumscribed_radius
 * /move_base/local_costmap/cost_scaling_factor
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_radius
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inscribed_radius
 * /move_base/local_costmap/lethal_cost_threshold
 * /move_base/local_costmap/map_type
 * /move_base/local_costmap/max_obstacle_height
 * /move_base/local_costmap/observation_sources
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_range
 * /move_base/local_costmap/origin_x
 * /move_base/local_costmap/origin_y
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency
 * /move_base/local_costmap/raytrace_range
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/transform_tolerance
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    explore (explore/explore)
    fake_localize (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)
    stage (stage/stageros)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [5461]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to e3e2f4c6-bca0-11e2-b4c1-001c259b7f6b
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5474]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[stage-2]: started with pid [5488]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[fake_localize-3]: started with pid [5503]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[move_base-4]: started with pid [5517]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
 [Loading /home/mohsen/fuerte_workspace/stage/world/willow-erratic.world]process[explore-5]: started with pid [5535]
[Image "willow-full.pgm"[ INFO] [1368541001.031481439]: Subscribed to Topics: base_scan
[ INFO] [1368541001.306642966]: Subscribed to Topics: base_scan
]
warn: worldfile /home/mohsen/fuerte_workspace/stage/world/willow-erratic.world:21 : property [laser_return] is defined but not used (/home/mohsen/fuerte_workspace/stage/build/stage/libstage/worldfile.cc WarnUnused)
[ INFO] [1368541002.140752250]: found 1 position/laser pair in the file
[ WARN] [1368541003.030337928, 0.800000000]: Message from [/stage] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [base_laser_link]. Resolved locally to [/base_laser_link].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ INFO] [1368541003.037880366, 0.800000000]: MAP SIZE: 1200, 1200
[ INFO] [1368541003.044607620, 0.800000000]: Subscribed to Topics: base_scan
[ INFO] [1368541003.361674617, 1.200000000]: Sim period is set to 0.05
[explore-5] process has died [pid 5535, exit code -4, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/exploration/explore/bin/explore __name:=explore __log:=/home/mohsen/.ros/log/e3e2f4c6-bca0-11e2-b4c1-001c259b7f6b/explore-5.log].
log file: /home/mohsen/.ros/log/e3e2f4c6-bca0-11e2-b4c1-001c259b7f6b/explore-5*.log
[ WARN] [1368541003.752455595, 1.600000000]: The base_scan observation buffer has not been updated for 0.30 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.20 seconds.
[ WARN] [1368541004.055580594, 1.900000000]: The base_scan observation buffer has not been updated for 0.60 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.20 seconds.
[ WARN] [1368541004.173130739, 2.000000000]: Message from [/stage] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [base_laser_link]. Resolved locally to [/base_laser_link].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[move_base-4] process has died [pid 5517, exit code -4, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/navigation/move_base/bin/move_base __name:=move_base __log:=/home/mohsen/.ros/log/e3e2f4c6-bca0-11e2-b4c1-001c259b7f6b/move_base-4.log].
log file: /home/mohsen/.ros/log/e3e2f4c6-bca0-11e2-b4c1-001c259b7f6b/move_base-4*.log
^C[fake_localize-3] killing on exit
[stage-2] killing on exit
^[[A[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

what am i should to0 do0?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62511/%22roslaunch-explore_stage-explore.launch%22-problem/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

you can find a temporary solution [in this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/62510/sigill-illegal-instruction-in-libpcl_commonso151-from-costmap_2d/?answer=62551#post-id-62551)

Also the next time you write a question try to do it a little bit more polite, it will be nicer to read. Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-05-14**:
Hello. i am beginner in english, and i was uneasy when asked. sorry "Marti Morta" @};